# COleDataSource/COleDropTarget cancel drag&drop operation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, drag-and-drop

I have implemented my custom drag&drop by deriving from COleDataSource and COleDropTarget. Everythings work fine but I have an scenario that makes the application crashes.

That happens when the dialog where the drag&drop controls are placed is destroyed while the user is in the middle of a drag&drop operation.
This is not usual because normally to close a dialog the user have to use the mouse or the keyboard and then the drag&drop operation is automatically canceled. But in this scenario the dialog can be closed due to an external condition (a custom message that changes the view) and then the drap&drop operation is not canceled.

So my question is, how can I programmatically cancel the drag&drop operation? 
The operation is started from the OnLButtonDown message handle calling COleDataSource::DoDragDrop.

**Update:**

I've implemented using DelayRender and it continues crashing. These are the two asserts I am getting:

1. When the mouse pointer (while dragging) is inside a control that is a COleDropTarget-derived class.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b34a62c5ac.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b34a62c5ac.jpg)

The assert is in the Revoke method and this is the line:

```
ASSERT(m_lpDataObject == NULL);
```

2. When the mouse pointer is not inside a COleDropTarget-derived class.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a0e8298490.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a0e8298490.jpg)

In this case the assert is in the destruction of the COleDataSource (in fact it is in its parent class CCmdTarget). In this line:

```
ASSERT(m_dwRef <= 1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what kind of data are you dragging? Are you using use COleDataSource::DelayRenderData() and COleDataSource::OnRenderData()?

Comment: No, I am not. I am using CacheGlobalData and GetGlobalData. Can you give an example on how the DelayRenderData works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work but you could try overriding the QueryContinueDrag method of the COleDropTarget instance and returning DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL in the case where the dialog has been closed

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. QueryContinueDrag is only called when there is a change in keyboard or mouse state and it is not could after OnDestroy (in the dragged/dropped control) and the actual destruction so I can not figure out how to use it.

Comment: At the end I used QueryContinueDrag to fix my problem. The problem at the beginning was that I tried to cancel the drag operation once the control was being destroyed. The solution is not to destroy the control until the drag operation is cancel...I set a timer and wait until the cancellation before trying to destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this type of crash starting with Windows Vista. Make sure the COleDataSource is created on the heap!

CYourDataSource *pSource = new CYourDataSource;
pSource->DoDragDrop();
pSource->InternalRelease();

Comment: I think it's better to call `pSource->ExternalRelease();` than `pSource->InternalRelease();`

Comment: sorry you were right `pSource->InternalRelease();` should be used here.